# Laravel pagination does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to create a pagination, the problem is, is that when I trying to create the pagination I get this error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::pagination does not exist.

I'm using laravel and livewire.

This is my code

```
    $products = $this->category->products->pagination(10);
```

This is in my Category model

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This is my whole code for my livewire

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire\Categories;

    use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    use Livewire\Component;

    class Show extends Component
    {
        public $category;

        public function render()
        {
            $products = $this->category->products->paginate(10);

            return view('livewire.categories.show', ['category' => $this->category, 'products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

and my livewire.categories.show blade file

```
<table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ $product->name }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    {{ $products->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: In your question you are calling `paginate()` on a Collection more than likely. In the answer that works you are calling `paginate()` on an eloquent builder.

Comment: I've tried that and I still got the same error but for paginate. I have tried something, but I'm getting another error. I'm not sure if I should add what I did to this question or create a new one

Comment: As @sta pointed out, the method name is wrong and you cannot access it from a collection. You could do `$products = $this->category->products()->paginate(10);` because using the method `product()` instead of the accessor `product` returns the query.

Comment: @IGP - I've done that and it's kind of working. I'm now getting this error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` and part of that error the url looks like this `http://laravel-site.test/livewire/message/category.show?page=2`

Comment: provide your complete code, then only the problem can be understood. We don't know whats your $this variable is pointing to. You need to check if your $this abstraction carries anything named category , then if the category contain any product collection then only you can put pagination

Comment: pagination should come from a get route. If you're returning it from a post route then there's not really a workaround that I know off.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my code for `$this` along with my blade file

Comment: change it to :  $products = $this->category->products()->pagination(10); just add braces

Comment: @OMR - I get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::pagination()`

Comment: sorry, ->paginate() like  IGP answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the `WithPagination` trait as stated in the [Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination#paginating-data).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Categories;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Show extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $category;

    public function render()
    {
        $products = $this->category->products()->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.categories.show', ['category' => $this->category, 'products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely forgot about the `WithPagination`